# CIL and Array Bound Checking

Tags: cil

Let us assume the following CIL program:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.assembly Program {}

.method private static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 4

    .locals init ( int32[] a,
               uint32   t )

    // Creates an array of int of size 10
    ldc.i4 10
    newarr int32
    stloc.0

    // Writes 0xaabbccdd at the index 2 of the array
    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4.2
    ldc.i4 0xaabbccdd
    stelem.i4

    // Loads
    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4 9 // <HERE>
    ldelem.i1

    stloc.1
    ldstr "Value: 0x{0:x8}"
    ldloc.1
    box [mscorlib]System.UInt32
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)

    ret
}
```

This program:

- creates an array of int size 10
- writes 0xaabbccdd at index 2 of the array
- tries to read one byte in the array using ldelem.i1
- prints the result

The trick is that I use "ldelem.i1" instead of the more standard "idelem.i4" for performance issues (I want to avoid doing masking) The idea is to access to the data of the array the way one does with pointers in C.

But things are not so nice because the program crashes (IndexOutOfRangeException) for indexes of more than 10 as argument for ldelem.i1.
This males the trick useless as I can't access data after the first half of the integer at the third index.

Ideally, I want to access bytes up to index 39, which corresponds to the last byte of the integer at index 9.

I would very much appreciate if somebody had some ideas on this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. The ECMA-335 states that it will throw an exception if the index is greater than or equal to the size of the array, which it definitely *is*. What surprises me about this isn't that the exception is thrown, but that the index is treated as a *byte* index into an *int* array in the first place - I can't see that that's specified anywhere.

I *suspect* you're into the realms of unspecified behaviour, quite possibly behaviour which isn't *intended* to be specified - I suspect you're just not meant to use `ldelem.i1` on an `int` array.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can picture how it is implemented under the hood, and I reached the same conclusion as you. Can you think about another method to achieve the desired behavior ?

Comment: For an alternative, MS C++/CLI uses empty structs with a `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=...)` attribute and pointer manipulation using `ld*a`, `add`, and `ldind.*`/`stind.*`.

Comment: @AntoineTrouve: You could use unsafe code from C#, fixing the array temporarily - then cast from `int*` to `byte*`.

Comment: An extra point: interestingly, this bug / undocumented feature works both ways, so while I am absolutely not recommending doing this for anything other than an experiment, you *could* create an array of 40 bytes and shove ints into it, instead of creating an array of 10 ints and reading bytes from it.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try and come back to you.

Comment: I ended up using the "other side hack": reading int in a byte array. I'm aware that's pretty dirty, but it's for a personal experiment.